# What does this strange code do?

Tags: c++

I found this weird code on the net but can't figure out what it does. When I compile it I don't get any output.

```
int main()<%auto f = <::><%%>;%>
```

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs

Comment: "What does this strange code do?" -- mark the author as quite the prankster. :-D

Answer (score 12):

Using digraphs, `<%` corresponds to `{`, and `%>` corresponds to `}`.

Substituting these in yields

```
int main(){ auto f = <::>{}; }
```

Finally, `<:` is equivalent to `[` and `:>` to `]`, so we end up with

```
int main(){ auto f = []{}; }
```

where `[]{}` is an empty lambda, and `f` is a copy of the closure object.

Answer (score 6):

It uses [digraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C.2B.2B) to obfuscate some simple code. It is exactly the same as

```
int main() { auto f = []{}; }
```

In other words, not much. It just instantiates an empty lambda, binding it to `f`. `f` isn't even called.